# Two quotient morphisms and universal property

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I am reading some notes on group theory and I am having some doubts related to the following:

Let $S \lhd G$ and let $\rho:G \to Q, \space \rho': G \to Q'$ be two quotients of $G$ by $S$. Then, by the universal property of $\rho$, there exists a unique $\overline{\rho'}: Q \to Q'$ such that $\overline{\rho'} \circ \rho=\rho'$. By the same argument, there exists a unique  $\overline{\rho}: Q' \to Q$ such that $\overline{\rho} \circ \rho'=\rho$.

In these notes it is affirmed that $\overline{\rho} \circ \overline{\rho'}=Id_{Q}$ and  $\overline{\rho'} \circ \overline{\rho}=Id_{Q'}$.

Now, I am not so sure why this is true, I've noticed that $\overline{\rho} \circ \overline{\rho'} \circ \rho=\rho$, if $\rho$ had an inverse, then the statement is immediate, however, $\rho$ does not necessarily has an inverse (unless $S=0=Ker(\rho)$), so from where it follows that $$\overline{\rho} \circ \overline{\rho'}=Id_{Q},$$   $$\overline{\rho'} \circ \overline{\rho}=Id_{Q'}$$

I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a unique(!) $\phi\colon Q\to Q$ such that $\phi\circ \rho=\rho$. Of course $\operatorname{id}_Q$ and $\overline\rho\circ\overline{\rho'}$ are also such morphisms, i.e. by uniquenes we have $\phi=\operatorname{id}_Q=\overline\rho\circ\overline{\rho'}$.